# Yeoman with git

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I am a complete new user of Yeoman. I am trying to learn the work flow of this Yeoman. So far I understand some of it but I am stuck in a very basic process.
Here is what I mean:
When I push all my directory to my repository it takes necessary files and folders. I used Yeoman .gitignor so that it ignores unwanted large files like bower_component

Other them member can clone my repository and run : **bower install && npm install**
to have all bower and npm components. and then run **grunt build** to make dist folder.

Upto now all works fine but my question is do they need to do same processes every time when they pull any new item ?
like I made some changes and pushed to my repository so what they have to do to get my new changes ? They need to do **bower install && npm install** again ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for really poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to run `bower install` and `npm install` again if any dependencies changed! Otherwise, it will make no difference.

The `git pull` command won't touch directories that are not versioned (that is, that were ignored).

Hey, perfectly understandable english. Do continue participating!